# Error Jest encountered an unexpected token on simple JS test

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, babel-jest

Getting this error when I try to run tests...

```
> cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest "--projects" "./jest.config.test.js"

 FAIL   test  <path>/schema.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    <path>/src/base.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import firebase from 'firebase/app';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/source-map-support/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-generator.js:8:17)
```

**The test itself is simple**

```
import schema from './schema';

describe('schema', () => {
    it('should be valid schema', async () => {
        expect.assertions(1);

        const validSchema = {
            budgetType: 'manual',
        };

        await expect(schema.validate(validSchema)).resolves.toStrictEqual(
            'Paul',
        );
    });
});
```

**My babel.config.js file**

```
/* eslint-env node */

module.exports = function (api) {
    const isDevelopmentEnvironment = api.env() === 'development';
    const isCI = !!process.env.CI;
    if (isCI && isDevelopmentEnvironment) {
        console.warn('You are loading babel in development mode but on CI');
    } else {
        console.log(`Loading babel in "${api.env()}" mode`);
    }
    api.cache.using(() => process.env.NODE_ENV);
    return {
        presets: [
            [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                {
                    modules: false,
                    loose: true,
                    shippedProposals: true,
                    useBuiltIns: 'entry',
                    corejs: 3,
                },
            ],
            '@babel/preset-react',
        ],
        plugins: [
            'macros',
            'syntax-async-functions',
            ['@babel/plugin-transform-for-of', { loose: false }],
            '@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator',
            [
                '@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions',
                { spec: true, loose: false },
            ],

            // Use built in `Object.assign`, otherwise Babel will include another polyfill.
            // @see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread#usebuiltins
            [
                '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
                { useBuiltIns: true },
            ],

            // Don't use loose mode, all iterables are assumed to be arrays.
            // @see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-spread.html#loose
            ['@babel/plugin-transform-spread', { loose: false }],

            [
                '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
                {
                    absoluteRuntime: false,
                    corejs: 3,
                    helpers: true,
                    regenerator: true,
                    useESModules: false,
                    version: '7.0.0-beta.0',
                },
            ],
            [
                'module-resolver',
                {
                    root: ['.'],
                    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
                    alias: {
                        '^routes$': './src/routes/index.js',
                        '^validator$': './src/validator.js',
                        '^base$': './src/base.js',
                        '^api/(.+)': './src/api/\\1',
                        '^hooks/(.+)': './src/hooks/\\1',
                        '^routes/(.+)': './src/routes/\\1',
                        '^helpers/(.+)': './src/helpers/\\1',
                        '^components/(.+)': './src/components/\\1',
                        '^icons/(.+)': './src/components/icons/\\1',
                        '^assets/(.+)': './src/assets/\\1',
                        '^pages/(.+)': './src/pages/\\1',
                        '^store$': './src/store/index.js',
                        '^store/(.+)': './src/store/\\1',
                    },
                },
            ],
            '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx',
            ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'],
            ['transform-react-remove-prop-types'],
        ],

        env: {
            production: {
                plugins: ['transform-react-remove-prop-types'],
            },
            development: {
                sourceMaps: true,
                presets: [
                    [
                        '@babel/preset-react',
                        {
                            development: true,
                            runtime: 'automatic',
                            importSource:
                                '@welldone-software/why-did-you-render',
                        },
                    ],
                ],
                plugins: [
                    '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source',
                    '@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name',
                    'react-refresh/babel',
                ],
            },
            test: {
                sourceMaps: true,
                plugins: [
                    '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
                    '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source',
                ],
                presets: [
                    [
                        '@babel/preset-env',
                        {
                            modules: 'commonjs',
                            loose: true,
                            // runtimeHelpers: true,
                            // useBuiltIns: 'entry',
                            corejs: 3,
                            targets: {
                                node: 'current',
                                browsers: 'defaults, not dead',
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                ],
            },
        },
    };
};
```

**And jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    displayName: 'test',
    // rootDir: 'src/',
    // rootDir: '.',
    clearMocks: true,
    errorOnDeprecated: true,
    testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen',
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.{js,jsx}'],
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/__mocks__/', '/mocks/'],
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            branches: 80,
            functions: 80,
            lines: 80,
            statements: -10,
        },
    },
    transform: {
        /**
         * Due the transform error
         * @see https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8006#issuecomment-625927890
         */
        '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': ['babel-jest', { rootMode: 'upward' }],
    },
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
    testMatch: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.test.js?(x)'],
    notify: true,
    notifyMode: 'failure-change',
    globals: {},
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        /**
         * Due the transform error
         * @see https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8006#issuecomment-609913705
         */
        '@babel/core/lib/config/files/index-browser.js':
            '@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js',

        '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
            '<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
        '\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
        routes: ['<rootDir>/src/routes/index.js'],
        validator: ['<rootDir>/src/validator.js'],
        base: ['<rootDir>/src/base.js'],
        'api/(.*)': ['<rootDir>/src/api/$1'],
        'hooks/(.*)': ['<rootDir>/src/hooks/$1'],
        'routes/(.*)': ['<rootDir>/src/routes/$1'],
        'helpers/(.*)': ['<rootDir>/src/helpers/$1'],
        'components/(.*)': ['<rootDir>/src/components/$1'],
        'assets/(.*)': ['<rootDir>/src/assets/$1'],
        'pages/(.*)': ['<rootDir>/src/pages/$1'],
        store: ['<rootDir>/src/store/index.js'],
        'store/(.*)': ['<rootDir>/src/store/$1'],
    },
};
```